# undefined method `visit_page' for #<Object:0x007fe29cb4c798> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bundler, rubymine, page-object-gem

My current issue only occurs when executing test from command line. When running the script from RubyMine I have no issues, from command line it looks like this

cucumber features/regression/createCloudUser.feature -r features/step_definitions/ -r lib/

Execution:

```
Feature: User pages Creation
  Add user to system

  Background:                   # features/regression/createUser.feature:4
Given you are in Cloud Staging # features/step_definitions/is_given_steps.rb:5
  undefined method `visit_page' for #<Object:0x007fe29cb4c798> (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/old_pages.rb:10:in `/^you are accessing User Page$/'
```

it points to the following page:

```
#is_given_steps.rb
When(/^you are accessing User Page$/) do
  defined? $base_url
  #pry
  visit_page CreateCustomerPage   #Error is on this line unsure why?
end
```

Here is the class:

```
require 'fig_newton'
require 'page-object'

class CreateCustomerPage
  include PageObject
  include DataMagic

  page_url "https://#{FigNewton.site_url}/admin/users/new"

  text_field(:first_name, :id => 'user_first_name')
  text_field(:last_name, :id => 'user_last_name')
  text_field(:user_email, :id => 'user_email')

  button(:create_customer, :name => 'commit')
  button(:cancel, :name => 'button')


  def customerIsCreated
    raise 'User Not Created' unless browser.text.include?("#{FigNewton.customer_created.to_s.strip}")
    return true
  end

  def customerIsNotCreated
    raise 'User was Created' unless browser.text.include?("#{FigNewton.customer_no_created.to_s.strip}")
    return true
  end

  def complete_user_creation (data = { })
    populate_page_with data_for(:create_user, data)

    create_customer
  end

end
```

project is set up as follows:

```
TestProj-|
         |--Config
         |--Feature
              |--Regression
                    |-- *.features
              |--step_definitions
                    |-- is_given_steps.rb    
              |--support
                    |-- env.rb
         |--lib
              |---pages
                    |--Common
                    |--IS
                        |--*.* (other files)
                        |-- CreateCustomerPage.rb
```

added env.rb

```
#env.rb
#ADDED THIS AS TEST
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/../../lib'

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../../', 'lib'))

require 'rspec-expectations'
require 'page-object'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'fig_newton'
require 'data_magic'
require 'require_all'
require 'time'
require 'date'
require 'yaml'
require 'fileutils'
require 'aws-sdk'

require_all 'lib'


$base_url = FigNewton.sys_url #used to parse a separate Url


World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

I am not sure why visit_page would throw an error on that page. When I execute from Rubymine I have no issue and the test runs successfully. Please help.

Comment: you are passing an object to `visit page` and not a `url`

Comment: that is [what you are supposed to do](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/page_factory.rb#L13-L17) @bjhaid

Comment: where is your env.rb? Can you post it?

Comment: @snowe2010 this is new to me, thanks!

Comment: the object needs to extend not include PageObject - see my answer below

Comment: sure I will add my env.rb

Comment: @RichardJordan When I extend I get a new Exception 'undefined method `page_url' for CreateCustomerYellowPages:Class (NoMethodError)'

Comment: Would anyone happen to know why it works perfectly fine when executing  through RubyMine? Maybe there is a dependency when runny from command line that RubyMine does on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are manually requiring folders, my guess is that you are not requiring the folder that includes the `env.rb`.

Given the project setup, I would guess that the `env.rb` is in the `support` folder. You need to include a require for this in your Cucumber command - ie `-r features/support`:

```
cucumber features/regression/createCloudUser.feature -r features/step_definitions/ -r lib/ -r features/support
```

Comment: That was it perfect!! works like a charm now!! Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 1):

This error

> undefined method `visit_page' for # (NoMethodError)

means that you have not initialized the page where visit_page lives.  You could require, or if you're doing a POM, you need to do something like this for where ever that step lives:

```
Given $/You are in Cloud Staging$/ do 
  @page = SomePage.new(@test_env) // initialize new object where method lives
  @page.visit_page
end
```